# Set ControlTemplate TemplateBinding in Code

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to set the Foreground in the code behing file. But setting `Foreground` doesn't change the visual style. FontSize btw works?

```
<ControlTemplate  x:Key="SimpleBtn" TargetType="Button">
      <Button x:Name="btnct" CommandParameter="{Binding Content}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ButtonClickCommand,ElementName=MainGrid}"
         keyImageProperty:KeyPressed.Image="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=gbutton70x70}" keyImageProperty:KeyNotPressed.Image="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=button70x70}" 
         Template="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=KeyboardButton}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
         FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontWeight="Medium" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"  />
 </ControlTemplate>

 <DataTemplate x:Name="btndatatemplate" x:Key="itemContDataTemplate" >
      <Button x:Name="btnstandard" Template="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=SimpleBtn}"                                 
                  FontWeight="Bold"
                  Content="{Binding Content}"     />
  </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Post your code-behind as well.

Comment: Where are you setting the Foreground property of the Button?

Comment: A Button in the ControlTemplate of a Button doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: You don't provide nearly enough context, nor explain clearly exactly what the problem is. The ControlTemplate by itself (with the 3rd line removed, since that contains references to things you have not defined here) works fine when applied directly to a Button.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for setting up templatebinding on the button in code behind (as part of a complete ControlTemplate definition):

```
var button = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button)) { Name = "btnct" };
button.SetValue(Button.ForegroundProperty, new TemplateBindingExtension(Button.ForegroundProperty));
```

FontSize works not because the templatebinding is working, but because FontSize is automatically inherited by child controls, whereas foreground is not. (Try the following in XAML:)

```
<Button FontSize="20" Foreground="Red">
     <Button Content="Click"/>
</Button>
```